# "ask for text" action in Apple automator does not receive focus automatically 

Tags: macos, automator

I wrote an Service using Apple's Automator. The first action is an "Ask for Text" action. However, when I trigger the shortcut to initiate the service, the modal asking for text pops up, but it does not have focus. I have to use the mouse to click on it.

Is there any way to have automator open this window with the focus on the text input?

Comment: this is driving me nuts right this very minute. i'll do some more research and if no love i'll start a bounty.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add some applescript to the top of your workflow with the following code. Just replace myapp with your app name

```
tell application "myapp"
activate
end tell
```

Comment: You can also just use 'activate' by itself.

Comment: I added an applescript action at the top of the workflow that just does "activate" and it works. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a sort-of, works-for-me, partial answer; instead of using the Ask for text action, I just used an applescript within my automator app (instead of the Ask..action, I used the "Run applescript" action). it looks like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set x to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter a version number" default answer "1134" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)


    return x
end run
```

My lil' automator application was to help me enter version numbers for tickets; using the mouse makes my hand hurt. The applescript dialogs seem to have focus properly, so enjoy! Let us know how you do!